# In chef remove a node from policy group

Tags: set, chef-infra, policy

I have set the node policy groups

```
 knife node policy set nodename 'xxxx' 'xxxx'
```

If I want to remove the node from policy groups, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use empty strings for the policy group and name:

```sh
knife node policy set nodename '' ''
```

If that does not work, you can edit the node and set `policy_name` and `policy_group` values to empty strings.

```sh
knide node edit nodename
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to clear the policy using knife node edit. nodename

Comment: Hi Draco, You seem to quite knowledgeable on Chef. Can you please look at this question and help me out. Thank you in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096253

Comment: Neither of these methods are working for me. Has something changed?

Comment: Nothing should have changed. Try `knide node edit` and remove the policy keys completely.