# chef policy group setting: Policyfile does not support setting the run_list in json data

Tags: chef-infra, nodes, policy

I have followed the steps in below article
I am getting following error

> Unexpected Error:
>   ----------------- Chef::PolicyBuilder::Policyfile::UnsupportedFeature: Policyfile does not support setting the run_list in json data.

here are the steps I followed

```rb
include_recipe 'basecookbook::default'

directory 'C:/ProgramData/ChefFiles' do
   inherits true
   action :create 
end
```

Updated cooksbooks metadata to specify dependency on base

The policy file is as follows
cookbooks/test01/Policyfile.rb
Changed the policy file to

```rb
name 'test01'
    run_list 'test01::default'
    cookbook 'test01', path: '.'
    cookbook 'basecookbook', path: '../basecookbook'
```

the policyfile.lock.json file is as follows

```
"name": "test01",
"run_list": [
  "recipe[test01::default]"
],
"included_policy_locks": [
],
"cookbook_locks": {
  "test01": {
```

I pushed the policy to chef and set the node to policy group and policy

```
chef push test01 .\cookbooks\test01\Policyfile.lock.json
knife node policy set NodeName 'test01' 'test01'
```

When I run the chef client on the node, I am getting following error

> Unexpected Error: Chef::PolicyBuilder::Policyfile::UnsupportedFeature:
>   Policyfile does not support setting the run_list in json data.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show how you are running the chef-client command on the node.  What you are probably doing is including a `-j` option to a JSON file which contains a `run_list` command.  The JSON being referred to in that error message is that `-j` argument, and has nothing to do with the `PolicyFile.lock.json` contents.  Either that or you may be specifying a run_list directly with a `-r` option on the command line (and the error message might be slightly misleading -- but it is certainly referring to the command line arguments)

When doing PolicyFile-based deployment the client has no capability to do dependency generation of cookbooks by design, so arbitrary run_lists being passed to the client is not supported, and the run_list has to come from the PolicyFile.lock.json and only that file (after being pushed up to the server with `chef push`).